# filecleared of fileinput Delete

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm using this plugin http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events
This event is executed by deleting all the uploaded or preloaded files, when you press DELETE BUTTOM
I need a similar event but when I delete a single file uploaded or preloaded with DELETE ICON
How can I do it?

```
$('#file-es').on('filecleared', function(event) {

    alert('aquí');

    $('div.alert').empty();
    $('div.alert').hide();


});
```

Comment: You mean a event for single file delete? In the documentation link provided, there is a `fileclear` event.

Comment: In the documentation says that in this version you can not control that event. There is another option: With release v4.1.8, you can manipulate events and add your custom validation through other events, by returning data for most of the events and use it for advanced processing. This functionality is supported for most events listed in the events section, except for the following events.

fileclear